# Banco de dados não funciona após formatar o computador

Tags: banco-de-dados, delphi-7

Galera, é o seguinte... Meu computador está dividido em duas unidades, `C` e `D`.

O programa que eu usava é em Delphi 7, estava na unidade `D` e usava um banco de dados do Firebird.

Quando eu formatei a unidade `C`, reinstalei o Delphi , FirebirdE IbExpert, assim como estava nas instruções (pois não fui em que fiz o programa),  agora ele da problema com o banco de dados.

Antes de formatar fiz um *backup* do banco pelo IbExpert e agora nem o *restore* eu consigo fazer e nem criar um novo.

Alguém tem alguma idéia do que seja?

Comment: jogou a dll do firebird no system32?